# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'HTMLScriptElement'

Tags: html, typescript, htmlelements

I have an issue with the type of attributes of HTMLScriptElement.

In the below code, the issue come at line:

> script[attribute.name] = attribute.value ? attribute.value : true

with the hint: "TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'HTMLScriptElement'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'HTMLScriptElement'."

```
const generateFromSource = (codeString: string) => {
    let script = document.createElement('script')
    let template = document.createElement('div')
    template.innerHTML = codeString

    const element = template.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
    for (let attribute of element.attributes) {
        if (attribute) {
            script[attribute.name] = attribute.value ? attribute.value : true
        }
    }
    document.head.appendChild(script)
}
```

Please help me with some suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing ***script*** local in order to get particular attribute hardly will work in JS: **script.getAttribute(attributeName)** will.
Setting particular ***script***'s attribute value might be done this way:

```
script.setAttribute(attribute.name, attribute.value);
```

Comment: I changed as your suggestion to this:  script.setAttribute(attribute.name, attribute.value ? attribute.value : true)          Then, I get this: "TS2345: Argument of type 'string | true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.   Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'."    It confused me, because some attribute take the boolean value.

Comment: My issue is solved: the link below deals with the boolean attribute. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute#examples